# Using CloudFlare domain on Wix or Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare, velo

I hope I am in the right place as I am ripping my hair out just starting. I am trying to build a small website for myself and having some issues. I just registered my domain with CloudFlare last week, and decided I wanted to use either wordpress or wix to build my site (I am a complete beginner and this is where I was told to begin).

The challenge I have is that in both cases it is not been easy to use my recently purchased domain through these platforms because they require me to change name servers through Cloudflare which requires a biz subscription of $300/mo.

I am at a point where I am happy to purchase a new temporary domain through WP or Wix to build my site if I will have the option to move m domain over with the existing site design once the no 60 day transfer period is up.

Is there any work around or advice you can give?

Sorry ahead of time for my complete beginner terminology etc.

Registered my domain on CloudFlare not realizing that I wanted to build it on Word Press or Wix

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the nameserver on Cloudflare domains for free. (source: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-default-nameserver-on-a-domain-registered-on-cloudflare/355978)

> I am at a point where I am happy to purchase a new temporary domain through WP or Wix to build my site if I will have the option to move m domain over with the existing site design once the no 60 day transfer period is up.

Yes you can, which is what I recommend as well, to transfer your domain to another registrar after 60 days, which includes Wix.com and Wordpress (see here: https://support.wix.com/en/article/transferring-a-domain-purchased-elsewhere-to-wix) (see here: https://wordpress.com/support/domains/incoming-domain-transfer/)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the pointing option rather than the nameserver change option. When you go to do the do the domain stuff it's at the bottom of one of the instruction pages in a smaller font on Wix and asks if you would rather point it instead

Comment: More specific information or even a screenshot would really help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34642059)